# Error calling WCF webservice through channelfactory - not permissioned

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I am using a ChannelFactory to call into a WCF service (as the target service location will change depending on environment and I need the URL to be configurable). However I get the error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

My calling code

```
var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(webserviceAddress);
var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IObjectService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
var serviceClient = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

My WCF service web.config system.servicemodel section

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The service should be authenticated based on Windows Authentication. I would have thought by default the calling code above would use Windows Authentication to pass the account that the code is running as (a service account) but it seems to be sending anonymous

Comment: Is your service hosted in IIS?  Is Anonymous authentication disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the mode to transport with message credentials, as shown in the following code:

```
var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
```

As an alternative, you can set the mode in the constructor of the binding:

```
var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
```

Also set the ClientCredential:

```
myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Though that message credential option is only for HTTPS which I do not have, only HTTP. I tried TransportCredentialOnly but it says mismatch between bindings, even though TransportCredentialOnly is what I have in my web.config?

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake regarding Security.Mode. I've updated my answer. Could you please post the entire error message ?